# Convert string into timespan using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I need to convert a string into timespan and to achieve this I have used following conversion,

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("12:00 AM", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan timeSpan = time .TimeOfDay;
```

Which is working well for everything except 12:00 AM, it is giving 12:00 for both AM/PM, which is OK for 12:00 PM but I need 12:00 AM as 00:00:00, is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Your code gives `00:00:00` for me.

Comment: 12:00 AM = 00:00:00, 12:00 PM = 12:00:00 for me as well

Comment: @SLaks Oh, actually yes, it is working fine, my bad I didn't debugged carefully, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below code:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("00:00", "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For more options check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ParseExact` instead of using that method use simple `Parse` method. but in order to cast to time use `HH:mm` format for `ToString` method.

```
DateTime timeAM = DateTime.Parse("12:00 AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime timePM = DateTime.Parse("12:00 PM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(timeAM.ToString("HH:mm"));
Console.WriteLine(timePM.ToString("HH:mm"));
```

Returns result similar to:

```
//00:00
//12:00
```